# IIS Permissions: 'Everyone' works, but IIS DefaultAppPool doesn't?

Tags: asp.net, permissions, iis-7.5

I got an error stating that the Site.master couldn't be found.  Changed permissions on folder to 'Everyone' and problem was fixed.  Of course, I don't want to leave it like that so I looked up the correct way to solve the issue and (after removing 'Everyone') added 'IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool'.

Now all I get is a spinny icon in the tab for the page.  It just spins indefinitely.  At least before it gave me a meaningful error, but now it just sits there and never even times out or does anything but spin.

What's the dealio?

Comment: @HatSoft Is that the "Best Practices" way, or is that just something that makes it work?  I'm not necessarily against just doing whatever gets it to work for the moment, however I am trying to understand stuff as I go along.

Comment: @HatSoft So do you have any idea why IIS AppPool is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an ID10T error.  I had the debugger attached and I forgot it was stopped at a break point.